# Qt qApp setFont()

Tags: qt

I am trying to use the setFont() method to set the font for application wide change. I tried the following:

```
qApp->setFont();
```

However, setFont() is not a method of qApp. I am not sure how I can go about setting the font for throughout the application. Could anyone please advise on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
//specify a new font.
QFont newFont("Courier", 8, QFont::Bold, true);
//set font of application
QApplication::setFont(newFont);
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked well! Give me a while for the system to allow me to accept this as the answer. :)

Comment: Would it be possible to change the background color for application wide through a stylesheet or any commands?

Comment: Thanks for accept, Wallace! It is definitely possible to change the background of the widgets by using stylesheets, take a look: http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_Change_the_Background_Color_of_QWidget

Comment: Great help there. I tried the following: `QApplication::setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 128);");`

However it returns me an error saying `"illegal call of non-static member function"`. Could you help advise on this?

Comment: setStyleSheet is a non-static method, try to use with an instance of widget like this: m_pMyWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color:black;");